# How to backup PostgreSQL which runs on the remote Docker container?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

How can I perform a backup of the remote PostgreSQL database? `pg_dump` is only available from inside the container, and, as I understand, if I want to install it on my local machine, I need to install the whole database, which doesn't seem like a good option.

SSH to the remote host is also not a good option, since I want to run backups on a daily/weekly basis, and save results to S3